# Why the style is not applied to the class Angular 5

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

The entered word is found in the text with the help of a regular expression and we wrap up it in `<span class = "match"> the word </ span>` using a pipe. Span and class are created, but the style for this class does not work. :(

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { PageService } from '../services/page.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'matchWord',
  pure: false
})
export class MatchWordPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private pageService: PageService) { }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const pattern = new RegExp(this.pageService.inputSearchText , "ig");
    value = value.replace(pattern, (str) => {
      return `<span class="match">${str}</span>`;          
    });
    return value;
  }
}
```

In HTML:

```
<p [innerHTML]="sentence | matchWord"></p>
```

I've tried it, but it doesn't work.

```
return `<span style="background-color:green;">${str}</span>`;
```

and

```
return `<span [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'green'}">${str}</span>`;
```

Comment: 'Does not work is not very helpful... did you check how html is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style is stripped off because of style encapsulation. In order to have it working try to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the `@Component` definition where you have this HTML:

`<p [innerHTML]="sentence | matchWord"></p>`

Something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sel',
  templateUrl: 'sel.component.html',
  styles: [],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If even the inline style does not work, it could be because your generated html is sanitised by angular.

Try using the `DomSanitizer` class to bypass sanitizing

**pipe.ts**

```
constructor(private pageService: PageService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

transform(...
let value = `<span class="match">${str}</span>`;          
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
```

You might also have some encapsulation issue depending on where your `match` class is defined.
If it's defined in your global stylesheet, then it will be fine. If it's defined in your component's css file, then you can either change encapsulation as indicated in jedruniu's answer, or use this:

**component.css**

```
:host ::ng-deep span.match
{
     // your style here
     background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case I used only this and it works
:host ::ng-deep .match { background-color: green; }